# Reactjs usestate logic in other js file and html logic in jsx file

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to write usestate login in other js file and html code in the jsx file. Is it possible?

sample.js

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("");
const [disablebtn, disableButton] = useState(true);

const triggerChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setValue(value);
    if () {
        disableButton(false);
    } 
};
```

sample.jsx

```
const app = () => {
return (
<>
<input type="text" onChange={triggerChange } value={value} />
<Button disabled={disablebtn} ></Button>
</>

)
}

export default app;
```

Comment: Manage your state `value` & `disablebtn` in `redux`

Comment: We are not using redux in our application

Comment: ok, and `Provider` & `useContext`? if data isnot pass from parent to child,find somewhere to manage your data is necessary,whether localstorage or redux or root component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it a custom hook: https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks

Though you should only do this if the hook will be reusable. If this code is only ever used by this component, then write it in the component. Mixing html(jsx) and logic is expected in react:

[image]